# Displaying The URL On a 404 Page In Gatsby

Tags: javascript, url, http-status-code-404, gatsby

Gatsby makes it easy to create your own custom 404 page [docs here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-404-page/), but I would like to display the URL on the page inside a message - something like:

> There was no page at '/example/nope'.

**Is there any way to access the failed URL from within the 404 page?**

Although I can't find any docs related to it, it appears that the 404 page receives a `history` object as one of its props, however this object doesn't actually contain any historical URLs, only an api to navigate to a previous state and the current url (which is `/404`).

Answer (score 3):

I looked at how Gatsby handles it for its own development 404 page and here are the relevant lines from `gatsby/dist/internal-plugins/dev-404-page/raw_dev:

```
 render() {
    const pathname = this.props.location.pathname
    ...
    return (
      ...
        <p>
          {`There's not a page yet at `}
          <code>{pathname}</code>
        </p>
     )
   }
```

So it is using the `location.pathname` of the props object which refers not to the current 404 page url, but the url of the page that caused the 404.

Note: this won't work if you visit `/404` to see your own 404 page in development as the 404 is not being generated in response to a missing page, so `location.pathname` will be `/404`